# Is it a bad idea to create a new Price for each new Subscription?

Tags: stripe-payments

For my application all I need is *one* product  because my users can only pay for a monthly or yearly subscription.

However, I am just not sure how to manage subscriptions and [`Price`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/prices)s (former plans) without unnecessary overhead.

Theoretically speaking, I could create a new [`Product`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/products) by setting the ID to `SUBSCRIPTION` (for example), which would be a known type on my backend, and create a new price object for each and every subscription users create.

The new API does not allow us to set an ID for a [`Price`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/prices/create) which means my backend has to know particular `Price` IDs and since prices can only be fetched if the ID is known, it would be required to store those IDs on my side. This complicates things on several ends in my oppinion.

That's why I thought I could just don't care about this at all and create a new price object for each new subscription using the `price_data`  field during creating a `Subscription` (see https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create#create_subscription-items-price_data).

This would be a lazy and simple solution but I am not 100% sure if it's a good idea to do it like this.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

While the API doesn't allow you to set a custom ID for Prices, you can do that when using the [Dashboard](https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/products).

The question is do you need to dynamically create Prices or can you create them beforehand and give them custom IDs in the Dashboard?

It sounds like you only need two Prices; monthly and yearly. If there's no dynamically set aspect of these Prices, then creating them beforehand is by far the easiest route.

There's ultimately nothing especially wrong with creating a new Price object for each new subscription, although it can make things quite messy. If you're comfortable with this approach (and possibly having to sift through lists of Prices in order to find the ones you want) then there's no real danger in doing so.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the reply. As far as I can see it's only possible to set an ID for a Product, but not for a Price. I could, however, just create two products with only one Price element each for monthly/yearly subscriptions. I'm still not sure which way to go because I want my backend to be able to deal with issues like a missing Product etc by itself. My current idea would be to create a local table of my own "Products" and check if there's a Stripe-ID available. If not, my backend creates one.